# Split multiple question answer from Google Forms by phrases in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I have a Google Sheet created after filling the Google Form with multiple answer questions

| Timestamp | Event | First name | last name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/10/2021 18:11:01 | Event A | Jane | Jones |
| 1/10/2021 18:12:35 | Event A, Event B | Joe | Jones |
| 1/10/2021 18:14:26 | Event B, Event C | Jennifer | Adams |
| 1/10/2021 18:15:35 | Event A, Event C | John | Smit |

The problem is that Event A and Event B may have commas itself like "Walk, Ride" or "Swim, Jump". In Google Sheets it looks like "Walk, Ride, Swim, Jump"

I want to split this multiple answers column by phrases "Walk, Ride" and "Swim, Jump" to get something like. How can I do that?

| Timestamp | Event | First name | last name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/10/2021 18:11:01 | Event A | Jane | Jones |
| 1/10/2021 18:12:35 | Event A | Joe | Jones |
| 1/10/2021 18:12:35 | Event B | Joe | Jones |
| 1/10/2021 18:14:26 | Event B | Jennifer | Adams |
| 1/10/2021 18:14:26 | Event C | Jennifer | Adams |
| 1/10/2021 18:15:35 | Event A | John | Smit |
| 1/10/2021 18:15:35 | Event C | John | Smit |

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=arrayformula({A1:D1;
query(
array_constrain(
{
flatten(split(rept(","&A2:A,len(regexreplace(B2:B,"[^\,]",))+1),",")),
trim(flatten(split(B2:B,","))),
flatten(split(rept(","&C2:C,len(regexreplace(B2:B,"[^\,]",))+1),",")),
flatten(split(rept(","&D2:D,len(regexreplace(B2:B,"[^\,]",))+1),","))
},
max(if(B2:B<>"",len(regexreplace(B2:B,"[^\,]",""))+1,))*counta(B2:B),4),
"where Col3 is not null",0)})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
={A1:D1; INDEX(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))="",, 
 TO_TEXT(A2:A)&"×"&SPLIT(B2:B, ",")&"×"&C2:C&"×"&D2:D)), "×")),
 "where Col2 is not null"))}
```

[image]